# Do go channels preserve order when blocked?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I have a slice of channels that all receive the same message:

```
func broadcast(c <-chan string, chans []chan<- string) {
    for msg := range c {
        for _, ch := range chans {
            ch <- msg
        }
    }
}
```

However, since each of the channels in `chans` are potentially being read at a different rate, I don't want to block the other channels when I get a slow consumer. I've solved this with goroutines:

```
func broadcast(c <-chan string, chans []chan<- string) {
    for msg := range c {
        for _, ch := range chans {
            go func() { ch <- msg }()
        }
    }
}
```

However, the order of the messages that get passed to each channel is important. I looked to the spec to see if channels preserve order when blocked, and all I found was this:

> If the capacity is greater than zero, the channel is asynchronous: communication operations succeed without blocking if the buffer is not full (sends) or not empty (receives), and elements are received in the order they are sent.

To me, if a write is blocked, then it is not "sent", but waiting to be sent. With that assumption, the above says nothing about order of sending when multiple goroutines are blocked on writing.

Are there any guarantees about the order of sends after a channel becomes unblocked?

Comment: I would advise to carefully wrap (capture) the variables used inside the goroutine into parameters : go func(ch2 <-chan string, msg2 string){ ch2 <- msg2 }(ch, msg) . Here is a small demo that not capturing lead to erratic behavior http://play.golang.org/p/9RTKvmRe5K

Comment: No further comment on the actual answer (which has been well explained already). Just wanted to point out that there is a package which implements a ring-buffered channel, so you don't have to write your own code to drop old messages: https://godoc.org/github.com/eapache/channels

Comment: I have the same question with yours. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77578420/does-golang-preserve-the-order-of-block-when-send-to-the-channel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there are no guarantees.

Even when the channel is not full, if two goroutines are started at about the same time to send to it, I don't think there is any guarantee that the goroutine that was started first would actually execute first. So you can't count on the messages arriving in order.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. What if I did something like Ask Bjorn Hansen suggested, but in the default case fired off a goroutine like in my example? Still no guarantee?

Comment: tjameson: what do you want to happen if the channel is full? If you don't want to drop the message, why not just make the channel longer? If you don't want to drop messages, but want to know how far behind a client is then make a channel "the other way" that returns a message number or some such so you can tell which message has been recieved/sent to the socket/whatever you do.

Comment: @AskBjørnHansen - I'm writing an IRC bouncer, so I think I want to drop the oldest. I can probably just do `if len(ch) == cap(ch) { <-ch } ch <- msg`, but if order is guaranteed, then maybe I'll wait n seconds for the client to catch up, then drop the client if it's too far behind. Since order isn't guaranteed, then I'll probably go with the former.

Comment: I'd do it the way I suggested as len() and cap() are documented in the spec to always return 0 (I don't they don't). Not sure if that's an oversight in the code or the spec: http://golang.org/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity

Comment: Aha, I asked golang-nuts and I misread the spec; len() and cap() does work on channels, just make sure you don't have a race condition when you check the length (either only have one goroutine writing to the channel or protect the writing with a mutex).

Answer (score 4):

You can drop the message if the channel is full (and then set a flag to pause the client and send them a message that they're dropping messages or whatever).

Something along the lines of (untested):

```
type Client struct {
    Name string
    ch   chan<-string
}

func broadcast(c <-chan string, chans []*Client) {
    for msg := range c {
        for _, ch := range chans {
            select {
            case ch.ch <- msg:
            // all okay
            default:
                log.Printf("Channel was full sending '%s' to client %s", msg, ch.Name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This solves my actual problem, but doesn't really answer my question. Thanks though! I forgot about `select` and full channels, and it forced me to review the spec and effective go and find a bunch of other nice things.

Answer (score 1):

In this code, no guarantees.

The main problem with the given sample code lies not in the channel behavior, but rather in the numerous created goroutines. All the goroutines are "fired" inside the same imbricated loop without further synchronization, so even before they start to send messages, we simply don't know which ones will execute first.

However this rises a legitimate question in general : if we somehow garantee the order of several blocking send instructions, are we guaranteed to receive them in the same order?

The "happens-before" property of the sendings is difficult to create. I fear it is impossible because :

1. Anything can happen *before* the sending instruction : for example, other goroutines performing their own sendings or not
2. A goroutine being blocked in a sending cannot simultaneously manage other sorts of synchronization

For example, if I have 10 goroutines numbered 1 to 10, I have no way of letting them send their own number to the channel, concurrently, in the right order. All I can do is use various kinds of sequential tricks like doing the sorting in 1 single goroutine.

Comment: Yeah, that question is what I was trying to get at. I could contrive an example using sleeps, but it seems there's no guarantee anyway. I'm guessing channels aren't a special case for the scheduler, which is what @andybalholm seemed to imply.

Answer (score 0):

This is an addition to the already posted answers.

As practically everyone stated, that the problem is the order of execution of the goroutines,
you can easily coordinate goroutine execution using channels by passing around the number of the 
goroutine you want to run:

```
func coordinated(coord chan int, num, max int, work func()) {
    for {
        n := <-coord

        if n == num {
            work()
            coord <- (n+1) % max
        } else {
            coord <- n
        }
    }
}

coord := make(chan int)

go coordinated(coord, 0, 3, func() { println("0"); time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) })
go coordinated(coord, 1, 3, func() { println("1"); time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) })
go coordinated(coord, 2, 3, func() { println("2"); time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) })

coord <- 0
```

or by using a central goroutine which executes the workers in a ordered manner:

```
func executor(funs chan func()) {
    for {
        worker := <-funs
        worker()
        funs <- worker
    }
}

funs := make(chan func(), 3)

funs <- func() { println("0"); time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) }
funs <- func() { println("1"); time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) }
funs <- func() { println("2"); time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) }

go executor(funs)
```

These methods will, of course, remove all *parallelism* due to synchronization. However,
the concurrent aspect of your program remains.

Comment: I haven't tested but I guess you can't guarantee that the goroutine with the expected number will run. I would add a "sleep" in "func coordinated" after coord<-n (within the else).

Comment: Yes, I can't be sure that the goroutine with that number will run. However, I can force execution of the function that does the actual work when it is time. The first solution is a bit of guesswork, while the second guarantees that the functions are called in order.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question title is really interesting, and the following test passes again, and again, and again when I run it on my OS X machine (and also on Ubuntu Jammy). I am interested in this because I'm using locks as described [here](http://www.golangpatterns.info/concurrency/semaphores). To me it looks like the answer to the question title is "yes", although I see why the question body describes a scenario where channel ordering won't save the OP from slow consumers.

```
import (
    "strconv"
    "time"
    "testing"
)

type Empty struct{}

func TestOrder(t *testing.T) {
    lock := make(chan Empty, 1)

    // array of ints to build by goroutines
    list := &[]int{}

    // long initial pause to force goroutines to queue up
    initialPause, _ := time.ParseDuration("100ms")

    doneCh := make(chan Empty)

    // work func
    add := func(i int) {
        lock <- Empty{}
        if i == 0 { time.Sleep(initialPause) }
        *list = append(*list, i)
        <-lock
        doneCh <- Empty{}
        if i == 9 { close(doneCh) }
    }

    // stagger 10 goroutines
    launchInterval, _ := time.ParseDuration("10ms")
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        t.Logf("Launching %d\n", i)
        go add(i)
        if i < 9 {
            time.Sleep(launchInterval)
        }
    }

    // wait for all goroutines
    for _ = range doneCh { }

    result := ""
    for _, n := range *list {
        result = result + strconv.Itoa(n)
    }

    if result != "0123456789" { t.Fatalf("Didn't work") }
}
```